# Update multiple properties on set of a single property

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I cant figure out how to update multiple properties before I notify the view about the changes.
I got a ViewModel with a Start as DateTime, StartTime as TimeSpan, End as DateTime and EndTime as TimeSpan.
When I set the StartTime I want to update End and EndTime accordingly. 
So if I set the StartTime to something later then EndTime, I wish to update EndTime to StartTime + 30 minutes. I used to work with WPF where I was able to update all the private properties in the ViewModel, and then call the PropertyChange event, but with this Prism I don't understand how to do this. It seems that I can only invoke the PropertyChanged event by using the SetProperty method. I have made a small example of what I thought I needed to do..

```
DateTime? _start = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan? _startTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
DateTime? _end = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan? _endTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
public TimeSpan? StartTime
{
    var val = value;
    _end = new TimeSpan(val.Hours, val.Minutes + 30, 0);
    SetPropertyChanged(ref _startTime, val); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
private int _myFieldA;
private int _myFieldB;

public int MyPropertyA
{
    get { return _myFieldA; }
    set
    {
        _myFieldA = value;
        _myFieldB = value + 10;
        OnPropertyChanged( () => MyPropertyA );
        OnPropertyChanged( () => MyPropertyB );
    }
}

public int MyPropertyB
{
    get { return _myFieldB; }
    set
    {
        _myFieldA = value - 10;
        _myFieldB = value;
        OnPropertyChanged( () => MyPropertyA );
        OnPropertyChanged( () => MyPropertyB );
    }
}
```

Those `PropertyChanged` events always fire one after another, though, but the data is always consistent, when one is fired.

Comment: It's funny, because I have tried something like that, and when I tested it it wouldn't work. But now when I started all over it works, I must have done something wrong the first time.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Better to express EndTime as StartTime + duration, and in the StartTime setter just call PropertyChanged for both properties.
Also you shouldn't be directly setting private fields used in VM properties.

Comment: Why should I not set private properties directly in the ViewModel?

Comment: Not properties, just fields backing the properties, so you won't forget to call PropertyChanged or anything you have in the setters.

Answer (score 0):

If you just set the property of EndTime instead of the backing field, it will call INPC for you (assuming you have a properly defined EndTime property).

```
public TimeSpan? StartTime
{
    SetProperty(ref _startTime, val);
    EndTime = StartTime + duration;
}
```